# Visual Studio 2010 Workflows not associating with list

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, feature-receiver

Probably a silly question: I have a vs2010 project with workflows in a site scoped feature.  When i deploy through visual studio the workflows are associated with lists.  However when i deploy manually they don't.  I'm guessing i have to associate through an event receiver or did i miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To associate a custom workflow to a list, you can use Features.
Write a Feature Receiver and write code to associate the Workflow to the List.

Here is sample code to associate a workflow : http://blogs.prexens.com/pages/post.aspx?ID=9

You can also use `AssociationCategories` Element in work flow definition. See here for details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543430.aspx

Answer (score 2):

if you setup workflow manually you should do these steps:

- Open List settings Tab on ribbon
- Click on arrow under workflow settings
- Click on Add workflow
- Choose your workflow from the list
- Setup workflow settings